# Apply CSS styles to Light DOM (shadow DOM) in custom element HTML5

Tags: javascript, css, html, polymer

I have read all the documentation about web components and according to the standards it is not possible to apply isolated CSS styles (shadow) to the elements that the user enters inside a custom element (light DOM), that is, the content that the user adds within a slot element, an example below:

```
<! - Custom element ->
    <index-book>
     <slot>

       <! - Light DOM here / This content was introduced by the user ->
       <div class = "container">
         <span class = "section"> Section title ... </ span>
         <ul class = "sections">
           <li> ... </ li>
           <li> ... </ li>
           <li> ... </ li>
         </ ul>
       </ div>

     </ slot>
    </ index-book>
```

In fact, making use of the pseudo-element class of CSS ::slotted () could apply styles only to the first direct child of the slot element, that is, to `div.container`, but not to its children.

I have reached two conclusions, or if you can apply Shadow styles to the entire structure of elements of the DOM light and I do not know how, or the second option is that the user should not be allowed to enter content into a slot that has multi -level as in the previous example, div within div ...

If the correct answer is the second one, how should I do so that the user inserts content within the custom element and the final result is the same or similar to the example shown above (trying to create a custom book index element) and can apply isolated styles in the DOM tree of the custom element.

I must mention that I am not using Polymer or any other library to develop this custom element.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Key point is the slotted **original** is **not** isolated because it is **not MOVED** to a slot; it **remains** in lightDOM. Thus you style slotted content in its correct scope/the host. In your example that is ``<index-book>`` **IF** that has shadowDOM, else you go *up-the-DOM*. So if you have one element with slotted content, styling is done in the global CSS scope. That means no "isolation" of styles; you have to do it with unique classnames/ids whatever.. just like regular DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

According to [web fundamentals](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom#styling):

```
<name-badge>
  <h2>Eric Bidelman</h2>
  <span class="title">
    Digital Jedi, <span class="company">Google</span>
  </span>
</name-badge>

<style>
::slotted(h2) {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: red;
}
::slotted(.title) {
   color: orange;
}
/* DOESN'T WORK (can only select top-level nodes).
::slotted(.company),
::slotted(.title .company) {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
*/
</style>
<slot></slot>
```

So I guess you're out of luck here.

However if it's light dom maybe you could style it directly or wrap it in another custom element?

Comment: Hi Lukasz,

As you comment, according to the web Fundamentals it does not cover the casuistic that I reflected in the previous example and that allows to encapsulate the CSS within the shadow DOM.

On the other hand I think that the option to wrap it in another custom element would not be useful because it would make the development and maintainability of the component very difficult.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use use normal CSS, that is bundled with your web component file, but applies to the normal dom instead of the shadowDOM, e.g.

```
<style>
index-book.container {
    color: red;
}
index-book.sections{
    color: blue;
}

/* or */
index-book > div {
    color: red;
}
</style>
```

Since these styles beging with the custom web component name, they will not apply to any other elements